# Can any measure be made into a bounded measure?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, probability-theory

Is it possible to derive a bounded measure from any measure on a measure space?
For example can the Lebesgue measure be made into a probability measure?

Comment: What do you mean by "made into"? The Lebesgue measure, for example, is a Haar measure on $\Bbb R$, unique up to scaling, so if you want it to be something that could be associated to it in some way, it should have similar properties, but all such (non-trivial) measure are unbounded.

Comment: In particular, the Radon-Nikodym theorem tells us that really you just pick any probability measure, and it will have some slightly associated lebesgue piece represented by a density function, plus some "invisible" singular piece plus a discrete piece, so that there's no real canonical-ness to any choice you might make in any way that's satisfying enough to say it's "made" from the Lebesgue measure.

And Radon-Nikodym is not unique to Lebesgue measure either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\mu$ be a measure and $f\in L^{1}(d\mu)$, $f\ge0$, and $\int fd\mu\neq0$ then $fd\mu$ is a bounded measure which can be normalized to be a probability measure. Such an $f$ can be found if the measure is semifinite. For Lebesgue measure we can take the measure $ce^{-\lvert x\rvert^{2}}dm$ where $c$ is a normalizing constant. The idea here was simply to multiply by a weight to make the measure a probability measure. To see that it can't be done for all measures consider the trivial measure.

Answer (score 2):

The question asking "Is it possible to derive a bounded measure from any measure on a measure space" I understand as follows: For a fixed measure $\lambda$, does there exist a probability measure $\mu$ which is equivalent to $\lambda$(under equivalence we understand that $\lambda(X)=0$ iff $\mu(X)=0$).

Then the answer for a $\sigma$-finite non-trivial measure is yes. For non-$\sigma$-finite measures the answer(in general) is no. Indeed, let consider the measure $\lambda$  constructed in [Baker R.,  ``Lebesgue measure" on $\mathbb{R}^{ \infty}$.
II. \textit{Proc. Amer. Math. Soc.} vol. 132, no. 9, 2003, pp. 2577--2591]. It is well known that the restriction of the $\lambda$ to the  $\sigma$-algebra of Borel subsets of $R^{\infty}$(for this restriction we preserve the same notation $\lambda$) is a non-$\sigma$- finite Borel measure which is not concentrated on a union of countable family of compact sets in $R^{\infty}$. If we   assume that there is a Borel probability measure $\mu$ which is equivalent to the measure $\lambda$ then we get that the measure $\lambda$ like $\mu$ is concentrated on  a union of countable family of compact sets in $R^{\infty}$. This is the contradiction.

Comment: Let $\mu$ be defined on the power set $\cal{P}(N)$ of $N$ as follows: $\mu(A)=+\infty$ if $A\neq \emptyset$ and $=0$ otherwise. It is obvious that $\mu$ is not $\sigma$-finite and $\cal{L}^1(d\mu)=\emptyset$ but there is a probability measure $\lambda$ on  $\cal{P}(N)$ which is equivalent to the measure $\mu$. Such a measure $\lambda$ can be defined as follows: $\lambda(A)=\sum_{n \in A}1/2^n$ for $A \in \cal{P}(N)$.

Comment: Now let $\mu_1$ is a counting measure defined on the power set $\cal{P}([0,1])$, i.e.,$\mu_1(A)=card(A)$ if $card(A)<\aleph_o$ and $\mu_1(A)=+\infty$ if $card(A)\ge \aleph_0$. Then the measure $\mu_1$ is not $\sigma$ finite and there is no a probability measure $\lambda$ defined on $\cal{P}([0,1])$ which is equivalent to the measure $\mu_1$.